# Proving $ \cos ^{2} \frac{\theta}{2} \equiv \frac{1+\cos \theta}{2} $

Tags: trigonometry

I need help proving LHS is identical to RHS.
$$
\cos ^{2} \frac{\theta}{2} \equiv \frac{1+\cos \theta}{2}
$$

Comment: This can't be answered without knowing what is assumed known and what is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's equivalent to proving $\cos ^2 \theta = \frac{1+\cos 2\theta}{2}$, which is equivalent to $$\cos2\theta = 2\cos ^2 \theta -1$$

And we know : $$\cos 2\theta = \cos (\theta + \theta) = \cos \theta \cos \theta - \sin \theta \sin \theta = \cos ^2 \theta - \sin ^2 \theta$$
$$= \cos^2\theta - (1-\cos ^2\theta) = 2\cos ^2 \theta -1$$

This gives the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with $\cos(2\theta) = \cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta$ and then use $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1.$ This will prove the identity with $\cos^2\theta = (1+\cos(2\theta))/2.$ For the first identity, use $\cos(a+b) = \cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b).$

Answer (score 1):

This is just the one of the *linearisation formulæ* deduced from the *duplication formulæ* :
$$\cos 2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1=1-2\sin^2\theta,$$
from which you get instantly:
$$\cos^2\theta=\frac{1+\cos2\theta}2,\qquad \sin^2\theta=\frac{1-\cos2\theta}2.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{(e^{i\phi/2}+e^{-i\phi/2})^2}{2^2}=\frac{e^{2i\phi/2}+2+e^{-2i\phi/2}}4=\frac12\left(\frac{e^{i\phi}+e^{-i\phi}}2+1\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Take the derivative:
$$
\begin{align}\left(\cos ^{2} \frac{\theta}{2} - \frac{1+\cos \theta}{2}\right)'&=2\cos(\theta/2)\bigl(-\sin(\theta/2)\bigr)\cdot\frac12-\frac12\sin(\theta)\\
&=\cos(\theta/2)\sin(\theta/2)-\frac12\cdot 2\cos(\theta/2)\sin(\theta/2)\\
&=0.
\end{align}
$$
Now substitute $\theta=0$.

Comment: If the OP knows derivatives *and also understands why the answer works* then he can hardly have problems with this basic trigonometry's question...

Comment: I'm a sixth-form student (16-18 years old in the UK). Perhaps I should find a different forum?

Comment: @MrRookie Not at all.  As Yves put it in his comment: "*This can't be answered without knowing what is assumed known and what is not.*"  The answers you've received came from three very different points of view -- that's math.stackexchange.  I presume the first three answers meet the background of a sixth-form student.